# How to role usage of c# IList interface type or other interface as type?

Tags: interface, ilist

IList is a interface. I have just started learning generics. And I know interface is a contract that class implements it promises to use its methods. So I never thought about it using like value type like:

Can someone please explain me what does this and how to think of its usage when using an interface like type:

```
IList<Writer> someName;
```

I am creating here generic typ of IList interface. But interface is not a class so how should I imagine it role?

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a member/variable is declared as an interface, it can be instantiated with any class that implements said contract. For example, you could instantiate `someName` with `List<Writer>()`, but not with `new IList<Writer>()`.

```
IList<Writer> someName = new List<Writer>();
// someName can access any member of IList, but not specific members of List
```

Comment: ok so what may I want to do in next step after instantiating IList with a new class that implement said contract/interface? Use of IList methods? If writer also must be implementing IList interface, why may I want to assign it to a IList interface?

Comment: Any member of the interface, but not members from the instantiated object that are not in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<Writer> someName;
```

Will hold a reference to any class instance that implements the `IList<T>` Interface, with `Writer` specified as the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Returning from list
        List<Writer> myWriters = new List<Writer>();
        myWriters.Add(new Writer("Andy", "FL"));
        myWriters.Add(new Writer("Mary", "FL"));
        myWriters.Add(new Writer("Ken", "CA"));
        myWriters.Add(new Writer("Robert", "WA"));
        myWriters.Add(new Writer("Brian", "CA"));

        IList<Writer> roWriters;
        roWriters = myWriters.AsReadOnly();
```

So can I say this; above using IList allow myWriters to use .AsReadOnly(); method? Otherwise it would not be possible? .AsReadOnly(); is a method of IList no List itself?

Comment: AsReadOnly() is a method of List. You can use `myWriters.AsReadOnly()` but not `roWriters.AsReadOnly()`. You can still use `.Add(item)` with both.

Comment: So what is the role of IList here?

Comment: In this case, it does nothing special. You could declare `List<Writer> roWriters` and this piece of code would do exactly the same thing. Its usually more useful when asking for a parameter or declaring a class field. For example, a method that prints on the screen a list of Something, you can ask the parameter to be a `IList<Something>`, and pass to it either a `List<Something>` or a `Something[]`, as both implement `IList<Something>`.